# Visual Studio 2008 setup project, how to block the folders from deleting during Uninstall?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, uninstallation

I have the following problem. After I uninstall the project - all folder is removing. But it contains the files which shouldn't be deleted. What could you advice me?

Ideally I would haeve the option which will be proposed to the user while uninstall with checkbox if it is necessary to delete this folder or not.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Files that shouldn't be deleted are data, and data shouldn't be in your program folder.  It should be in the application data folder.